# Why does fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag return allways null?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Inflating Views is expensive, so I'm trying to reuse my fragments, which get initiated on selection of the associated navigation drawer item. After reading a bit the common way seems to be to call the FragmentTransition.replace method with a tag parameter and then when needed again use the findFragmentByTag method.

Now my problem is, that the findFragmentByTag ALLWAYS returns null. I'd understand if it were sometimes null due to GC, but that it's allways null seems kinda wrong to me. So something must be wrong with my sourcecode.

I've found many threads where people had the same issue, but the ussual solution was to either add the tag in the replace call or some typo in the tag in either the replace or the findFragmentByTag call. Sadly both aren't the issue at hand.

The onNavigationDrawerItemSelected is the only method in the mainactivity, which in any way touches the Fragments. It gets called in the onCreate of the Navigationdrawer, so that the app start on the Map_Fragment.

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    String method = "MainActivity.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected";
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment replacerFragment = null;

    String usedTag = "";
    switch(position){
        case 0:
            usedTag = Map_Fragment.FRAGMENT_TAG; //which is "MAP_FRAGMENT"
            replacerFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(usedTag);
            if(replacerFragment == null){
                replacerFragment = Map_Fragment.newInstance();
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            usedTag = Setting_Fragment.FRAGMENT_TAG; //which is "SETTING_FRAGMENT"
            replacerFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(usedTag);
            if(replacerFragment == null){
                replacerFragment = Setting_Fragment.newInstance();
            }
            break;
    }

    Log.i(method, "usedTag: " + usedTag); //prints the correct tag
    if(replacerFragment != null) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, replacerFragment, usedTag).commit();
    }
}
```

What the fragments currently are is:

```
public class Setting_Fragment extends Fragment {
    public final static String FRAGMENT_TAG = "SETTING_FRAGMENT";

    public static Setting_Fragment newInstance() {
        Log.i("Setting_Fragment.newInstance", "boing");
        Setting_Fragment fragment = new Setting_Fragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(getString(R.string.fragment_title_settings)); //changes the Title of the Activity
    }
}
```

Comment: Your fragments won't have a tag until you set one when you call `replace()`. So you can't call `findFragmentByTag()` unless you've already used that Fragment to replace another one, and you set a tag for it in the `replace()` call.

Comment: that would be the first time it happens. What about the 20 times the method gets called afterwards? Start -> Map -> Setting -> Map -> Setting -> Map... every time a new Fragment gets created

Comment: Well your code above doesn't show the first time it happens. Your code above assumes a tag was successfully set somewhere else. So if you are setting the tag in an initial `inflate()` call, post that code, or if you are initially setting tags in a `FragmentTransaction`, post that code. A tag can only be set in an `inflate()` call or a `FragmentTransaction`.

Comment: Ofcause at the start it doesn't have the fragments or its tags, so it can't find them, so it creates a new instance (because the result is null). But doesn't `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, replacerFragment, usedTag).commit();` set the tag, which should result in the fragment being found the next time the fragment with the tag is required?

Comment: Yes I see that, my mistake. Try adding `transaction.addToBackStack(null)` before you commit the `replace()`. If you don't add that line, the fragment that gets removed during the `replace()` will get destroyed instead of just being stopped. You'll have to separate your transaction statements to add that line.

Comment: That does the trick, thank you =)

Comment: Added my answer below. If you feel it solves your issue, please accept it as the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the line `addToBackStack(null)` to your FragmentTransaction before committing. This makes it so when a previous Fragment is removed from view, it will just be stopped and not destroyed.

This is stated in the [docs here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html):

> **Note:** When you remove or replace a fragment and add the transaction to the back stack, the fragment that is removed is stopped
>   (not destroyed). If the user navigates back to restore the fragment,
>   it restarts. If you do not add the transaction to the back stack, then
>   the fragment is destroyed when removed or replaced.